# Menu, submenus NAV Bootstrap dinâmicos com PHP PDO Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bootstrap

Boa noite.

Preciso montar um menu dinâmico, de três tabelas, que precisam estar interligadas, mas estou perdido. Segue uma parte do organograma abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No momento, tenho o seguinte código:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Produtos<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Audiologia</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

      <?php

      require 'conexao.php';

      $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE categoria_id = '1' ORDER BY ID;");

      while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

      <li><a href="produto.php?id=<?php echo "$linha[id]"; ?>"><?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?></a></li>

      <?php } ?>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <?php

        require 'conexao.php';

        $consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE categoria_id = '1' AND subcategoria_id = '1' ORDER BY ID;");

        while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

        <li><a href="produto.php?id=<?php echo "$linha[id]"; ?>"><?php echo "$linha[titulo]"; ?></a></li>

        <?php } ?>

      </ul>

    </ul>
</li>
```

No meu banco de dados, tenho as tabelas:

CATEGORIAS = com as categorias principais, ID e CATEGORIA.

SUBCATEGORIAS = com os campos ID, CATEGORIA_ID e SUBCATEGORIA.

PRODUTO = com os campos ID, CATEGORIA_ID, SUBCATEGORIA_ID e TÍTULO.

Consigo, à partir deste código, ter a categoria e a sub categoria, mas não o produto. Não creio que essa seja a forma correta de fazer, gostaria de instruções.

Comment: Sei que não é sobre a pergunta, mas você não precisa colocar dois require para conexão.

Comment: Tem razão... vou corrigir isso... é o cansaço... obrigado pelo toque

Answer (score -1):

Assim o código fica menor e mais fácil de enxergar, por mais que o meu código não esteja 100% do jeito que você precisa, para ajustar fica mais simples desta forma.

Na segunda query eu coloquei para ele pegar o id da primeira query e caso você precise utilizar mais um foreach para as categorias eu deixei separado a variável $id_categoria para ficar mais simples de substituir.

```
<?php
require 'conexao.php';
$id_categoria = 1;
$consulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE categoria_id = '".$id_categoria."' ORDER BY ID;");
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $categoria[$linha['id']]['titulo'] = $linha['titulo'];
    $subconsulta = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE categoria_id = '".$id_categoria."' AND subcategoria_id = '" . $linha['id'] . "' ORDER BY ID;");
    while ($sublinha = $subconsulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $categoria[$linha['id']]['subitens'] = array($sublinha['id'], $sublinha['titulo']);
    }
}
?>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Produtos<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Audiologia</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php foreach($categoria as $indice => $item): ?>
        <li><a href="produto.php?id=<?php echo $indice; ?>"><?php echo $item['titulo']; ?></a></li>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <?php foreach($item['subitens'] as $subindice => $subitem): ?>
            <li><a href="produto.php?id=<?php echo $subindice; ?>"><?php echo $subitem; ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela pronta resposta. Ainda tem algo errado, a subcategoria não carrega...

Comment: esqueci da '' na $linha['titulo'], editei agora.

Comment: Acredito que a lógica esteja certa, mas algo não fecha... uso o Sublime, depois do `categoria_id = '".$id_categoria."'` o AND e o ORDER BY ID não ficam vermelho, como de costume no programa. Alguma aspa? Sei lá... :(

Comment: Coloquei o código no notepad++ não deu este problema, mas você pode tentar desta forma: "SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE categoria_id = '$id_categoria' ORDER BY ID;", que funciona da mesma forma.

Comment: Nada feito. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: O que eu preciso colocar é: CATEGORIA --> SUBCATEGORIA --> PRODUTO. Não consigo enxergar onde está o erro.

Comment: Tente ver o que esta retornando coloque embaixo dos whiles var_export($categoria); para enxergar o que ele esta pegando.

Comment: NULLarray ( 1 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, ), )array ( 1 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, 'subitens' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => 'teste', ), ), )array ( 1 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, 'subitens' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => 'teste', ), ), 2 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, ), )array ( 1 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, 'subitens' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => 'teste', ), ), 2 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, ), 3 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, ), )array ( 1 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, 'subitens' => array ( 0 => '1', 1 => 'teste', ), ), 2 => array ( 'titulo' => NULL, ).....

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

```
<?php require_once('conexao.php');
$id_categoria = 1;
$consulta = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE categoria_id = :idCategoria ORDER BY ID;");
$consulta->bindParam(':idCategoria', $id_categoria, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$consulta->execute();
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $categoria[$linha['id']]['titulo'] = $linha['titulo'];
    $subConsulta = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE categoria_id = :idCategoria AND subcategoria_id = :idSubcategoria ORDER BY ID;");
    $subConsulta->bindParam(':idCategoria', $id_categoria, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $subConsulta->bindParam(':idSubcategoria', $linha['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $subConsulta->execute();
    while ($sublinha = $subConsulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $categoria[$linha['id']]['subitens'] = array($sublinha['id'], $sublinha['titulo']);
    }
}
?>

<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Produtos<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Audiologia</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php foreach ($categoria as $indice => $item) { ?>
                    <li><a href="produto.php?id=<?php echo $indice; ?>"><?php echo $item['titulo']; ?></a></li>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php foreach ($item['subitens'] as $subIndice => $subitem) { ?>
                            <li><a href="produto.php?id=<?php echo $subIndice; ?>"><?php echo $subitem; ?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```